# Prove $\int_0^{\pi/2}{(\sin^nx-\cos^nx)}dx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, proof-writing

How do I show that

> $$\int_0^{\pi/2}{(\sin^nx-\cos^nx)}dx=0$$ for all $n>0,n\in Z$

I know that it is true, but I don’t know how to prove.

Comment: We could note that over the interval which we are integrating, the sine and cosine functions take on the same values, and hence $ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n x \mathop{dx} =  \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n x \mathop{dx}$. This is the essence of the solution already posted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, note that:

$$\int_0^kf(x)\,dx=\int_0^kf(k-x)\,dx$$

Therefore, we now have that:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n}x-\cos^{n}x\,dx
&
=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x\right)-\cos^{n}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\,dx \\
&
=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^{n}x-\sin^{n}x\,dx \\
&
=-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n}x-\cos^{n}x\,dx \end{split} \end{equation}$$

$$\therefore\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n}x-\cos^{n}x\,dx=-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n}x-\cos^{n}x\,dx$$

This integral is equal to its additive inverse. $0$ is the only number with this property.